# Value is discarded in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

I don't understand why this happens:

```Haskell
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Reader

data Config = Config Int

getA :: (Monad m) => ReaderT Config m Int
getA = do
  Config a <- ask
  return a

readConfig :: Config -> IO Int
readConfig = runReaderT getA

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print "Start"
  let a = Config 2
  b <- readConfig a -- Will be printed
  print b
  let c = Config 4
  print <$> readConfig c -- Silence, nobody complains..
  print "Done"
```

the result is just:

```bash
"Start"
2
"Done"
```

Why is `print <$> readConfig a` empty? Even with `-Wall` nobody complains about this...

(I tried diff ghc versions in godbolt but the result stays the same)

**Edit:**
Ok, I found an equivalent description of the problem, thx to @chi and @David:

```Haskell
module Main where
test :: IO ()
test = do 
    print "test"
    return ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let t = test -- equivalent to print <$> readConfig c, is IO (IO ())
  test -- equivalent to print b is IO ()
```

Now, I'm just wanting to know why `let t` does not evaluate. From my intuition, it was obvious before but not anymore... But there are answers to this ([esp. from Tanner Swett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228189/10236449))

Comment: `do { a <- foo; return a }` can also be spelled `foo` -- it's a `Monad` law!

Comment: Related example: `x <- print 3` prints 3 and binds `()` to `x`, while `x <- return (print 3)` doesn't print anything, and binds the IO action `print 3` to `x`.

Comment: chi and @Daniel, I appreciate your comments, but I do not understand how I should apply them to my problem. Do you want to point out some identity function for Monads? Is it somehow related to the answer from David?

Comment: @blauerreimers The refactor I suggest (compare your definition of `readConfig` to the template in my comment) is unrelated to your problem. It has to be -- it's a `Monad` law! That's (part of) why I posted this as a comment rather than an answer. Also, I believe chi's comment is unrelated to mine; the "Related example" opener is justified by it being closely related to your problem.

Comment: @Daniel Ah, typical tunnel vision syndrome - I did not look anywhere above the main block and didn't see the connection...refactoring! ty

Comment: @chi Ah, ok, I see now. It guess it is the same additional question to the answer from David. I wonder why `()` gets evaluated (from `x <- print 3), while `( IO () )` doesn't' (from `x <- return (print 3)`).

Comment: @blauerreimers Because IO action execution only happens when you do something like `... <- x`, otherwise you simply pass the action around without running it. You can roughly think of an IO action as an OOP object with a method "run": passing the object around, returning it, copying it, etc. does not call the method. It's the same principle used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624408/equal-vs-left-arrow-symbols-in-haskell/28625714#28625714).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GHC 8.10.3 does complain about this with -Wall (after I changed `initConfig` to `readConfig` in your code):

> A do-notation statement discarded a result of type ‘IO ()’
> Suppress this warning by saying ‘_ <- print <$> readConfig c’

You have `readConfig c` of type `IO Int`.  Then you fmap `print`, giving something with a type of `IO (IO ())`.  Since the result isn't bound to a variable in the do block, it is thrown away.

In the fmap's type `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` we have `f` being `IO`, `a` being `Int`, and `b` being `IO ()`.  So it is used with the type `(Int -> IO ()) -> IO Int -> IO (IO ())`.

This would work:

```
printAction <- print <$> readConfig c
printAction
```

But what you actually want is a bind:

```
print =<< readConfig c
```

Comment: Ty, this is still a hard nut to me: `IO (IO ())` does not get evaluated, because it is not used - this makes sense to me. But the monad `=<<` does ( `IO ()` ). Is it because, of the operation from `IO( IO ())` to `IO ()`? (Still, I ignore the result, so why is it evaluated?).